# Integral involving exponential function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, exponential-function

Can you give any hints how to solve the integral
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} {\exp \left( \frac{-w (z-u)^2}{2u^2 z}  \right) dz}
$$
for $u>0, w>0$, or does no close form exist? Substitution seems to be difficult…

Comment: I would suggest expanding the square: $\frac{-w(z- u)^2}{2\mu^2z}= \frac{-wz^2+ 2wuz- wu^2}{2\mu z}= \frac{-w}{2\mu}z+ \frac{wu}{\mu}- \frac{wu^2}{2\mu}\frac{1}{z}$.  The "1/z" is the hard part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{w\bracks{z - u}^{2} \over 2u^{2}z}}\,\dd z =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{w \over 2u^{2}}\,
\bracks{\root{z} - {u \over \root{z}}}^{2}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\root{z}\ =\ \root{u}\expo{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,&
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{2w \over u}\,
\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}}\pars{2u\expo{2\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{2w \over u}\,
{\cosh\pars{2\theta} - 1 \over 2}}\bracks{\sinh\pars{2\theta} + \cosh\pars{2\theta}}\,2\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
2u\expo{w/u}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{w \over u}\,
\cosh\pars{\theta}}\cosh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-2u\expo{w/u}\partiald{}{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\,z\cosh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ w/u}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2u\expo{w/u}\,\underbrace{\mrm{K}_{0}'\pars{w \over \mu}}
_{\ds{-\,\mrm{K}_{1}\pars{w/u}}}\,,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\verts{\mrm{arg}\pars{w \over u}} < {\pi \over 2}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\,\mrm{K}_{\nu}}$ is a
>   *Modified Bessel Function*. See
>   [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_376.htm).

---

$$
\bbx{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{w\bracks{z - u}^{2} \over 2u^{2}z}}\,\dd z =
2u\expo{w/u}\,\mrm{K}_{1}\pars{w \over u}}
\qquad\qquad
\verts{\mrm{arg}\pars{w \over u}} < {\pi \over 2}
$$

Comment: @jana1802 Fixed. Thanks. It's funny yesterday it was right but last night I 'recheck' everything and made the mistake you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

By expanding the square and performing a substitution we have that the given integral depends on a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), since

$$ \forall \alpha>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\alpha\left(w+\frac{1}{w}\right)\right)\,dw = 2\cdot K_1(2\alpha).$$