# Improper integral with exponential function

Tags: integration, exponential-function, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to solve an improper integral that can be reduced to the following form

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|}\exp\left(-\frac{a}{x^2} - \frac{(x + b)^2}{c|x|} \right)dx$$

for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, known scalar constants.

It's similar in spirit to [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187777/compute-integral-of-exponential-with-polynomial-division-in-argument) and [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313908/integral-involving-exponential-function?rq=1) which is just the second term within the exponential. Both of those integrals have closed-form solutions in terms of the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

I've tried giving a similar treatment to this specific integral but to no avail. I've evaluated it numerically and I know it converges. Its plot resembles modified Bessel functions, so my intuition was that I should be able to obtain a closed-form solution for it, likely also in terms of the modified Bessel function family.

Any ideas on how to tackle it? Is there a known integral representation that has this shape?

Comment: You might want to start by clearing $|x|$ by splitting it into two integrals: one from $0 \to \infty$, and another one from $-\infty \to 0$ where $x$ os replaced with $-x$. That may make it slightly more tractable.

Comment: For $a<<b^2$, expanding the first exponent then integrating produces the series $4 \cosh(2b) \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} (a/b^2)^n K_{2n}(2b)$

Comment: @Sal, thanks a lot for your answer. I would like to briefly point out that you missed the constant $c$ in your solution (maybe you absorbed it into $b$), but for the sake of completeness here's the solution making $c$ explicit.

$$ I = 4\cosh(2b/c) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(a/b^2)^nK_{2n}(2b/c) $$

which also exposes the need for $2b >> c$ for the series to converge (at least by numerical evaluation that seems to be the case).

Comment: @CarlosLuis No problem. You are correct, I forgot the constant $c$

Comment: @CarlosLuis You can use [$(10.41.2)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.E2) to determine the precise condition for convergence.